# Merge nested object with array of objects with deepmerge

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, array-merge

I am using library https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge to deep merge two nested objects with array of objects but I am not getting expected result.

```
       const x = {
                foo: { bar: 1 },
                loo: {
                  array: [
                    {
                      too: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { bar: 3 }, { bar: 4 }, { bar: 5 }],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              };

              const y = {
                foo: { bar: 4 },
                loo: {
                  array: [
                    {
                      too: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { bar: 3 }, { bar: 4 }, { bar: 5 }],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              };
```

and `console.log(deepmerge(x, y));` gives me this result:

```
        const result = {
                foo: { bar: 4 },
                loo: {
                  array: [
                    {
                      too: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { bar: 3 }, { bar: 4 }, { bar: 5 }],
                    },
                    {
                      too: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { bar: 3 }, { bar: 4 }, { bar: 5 }],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              };
```

but I would expect this:

```
              const expectedResult = {
                foo: { bar: 4 },
                loo: {
                  array: [
                    {
                      too: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { bar: 3 }, { bar: 4 }, { bar: 5 }],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              };
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have a look at this answer. It's working perfectly: stackoverflow.com/a/72080411/6666348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this section of the doc](https://github.com/TehShrike/deepmerge#api), it mentions that

> By default, arrays are merged by concatenating them.

So you have to provide another option to override this default behavior, this is mentioned below, by using `arrayMerge` option

```js
const x = { foo: { bar: 1 }, loo: { array: [{ too: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { bar: 3 }, { bar: 4 }, { bar: 5 }], }, ], }, };
const y = { foo: { bar: 4 }, loo: { array: [{ too: [{ bar: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { bar: 3 }, { bar: 4 }, { bar: 5 }], }, ], }, };

console.log(
  deepmerge(
    x,
    y,
    { arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray, options) => sourceArray }
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/deepmerge@4.2.2/dist/umd.js"></script>
```